# Java parsing XML through continous stream instead of file

Tags: java, xml, parsing, stax

I am working on a project that is using an XML data generator. The generator puts data through a port, which i read using a number of sockets.  I use StAX for parsing the data to a script that puts the data.

The problem I have has to do with the parsing of the data. Everybody on the web is using an XML file to get data, but that is not usefull for me. The generator generates about 60mb per minute (about 2 million lines), so I don't think a file is very usefull. Also, we will write and read/delete data from the file at the same time.

Does anybody have a suggestion on what to use for parsing XML data through StAX from a stream instead of a file?

Comment: Have you looked at constructors that take in an `InputStream` instead of `File` (or other file based parameter)?

Comment: [some tutorial](https://softwarecave.org/2014/02/18/parse-xml-document-using-streaming-api-for-xml-stax/) if you interested..

Comment: I tried using InputStream but that did not work out. @Kayaman

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial @Bagus

Comment: Why did not using `InputStream` work? This is in principle what you will need to use in the end anyways (since it is the standard Java representation of a data stream), so you need to resolve this rather than trying to avoid using it.

Comment: I have no idea, maybe I used it in the wrong way. @JiriTousek

Answer (score 2):

The `XMLInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader` from standard `javax.xml.stream` package takes a `Reader` as the source of data. `Reader` can read from any `InputStream`, not necessarily from a file.

Whichever StAX library you use, there's a good chance it will be able to read input from the general `Reader` / `InputStream` as well.